# C# WPF pages information

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a bunch of WPF userContol in my project with a bunch of textboxes and datepickers the idea is to get all the data from all the pages, when the user click the submit button on the last page, and fill a pdf form.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="FormFiller.Pages.UserInfo"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="lblName" Content="EMPLOYEE'S NAME (Last, First, Middle Initial)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="263" Foreground="#FF151212" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxEmpName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="23,90,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="201">
            <TextBox.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8DC1F5" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TextBox.BorderBrush>
        </TextBox>
        <Label x:Name="lblDateAssigned" Content="DATE ASSIGNED PRESENT POSITION" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="338,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF151212" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <DatePicker x:Name="DpAssigned" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="357,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblduedate" Content="DUE DATE OF WITHIN-GRADE INCREASE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,158,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="241" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <DatePicker x:Name="DpDue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,196,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblPeriod" Content="PERIOD COVERED BY THIS PERFORMANCE PLAN" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="298,158,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="298" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <DatePicker x:Name="DpFrom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="323,201,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblFrom" Content="From" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="346,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblTo" Content="To" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="509,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <DatePicker x:Name="DpTo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="471,201,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

any idea on how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ViewModel with fields for each of your FrameworkElements and set up bindings so that they update those fields as the user interacts with them. Then add an RelayCommand to your ViewModel and bind the "Submit" button's command handler to it. When the RelayCommand's handler is called all the data will be ready to save using whatever PDF 3rd-party library you prefer.

Comment: Just to paraphrase/elaborate on this answer: there is no reason why you cannot bind several different views to one concrete instance of one viewmodel. If you want to restrict what each view can "see" in the VM just implement an interface on the VM for each view, the view should access it by that interface only (although the interface is totally transparent/nonexistent as far as the binding subsystem is concerned).